# disable spring autowire

Tags: spring, struts2, autowired, struts2-spring-plugin

i ahave an app with struts2.2 and spring 3.1 and i want to disable spring autowire.
I googled a little bit and found that i have to put at `<beans>` tab `default-autowire="no"`, but this doesn't seems to work.

Then i fount that i can declare this for every `<bean>` tag like this : `<bean autowire="no">`, but this does not seems to work either.

When i enabled spring debug logger i can see a lot aof messages like this :

> INFO: DEBUG [http-thread-pool-8080(3)] (ConstructorResolver.java:739) - Autowiring by type from bean name 'com.common.actions.PopupAction' via constructor to bean named 'intermedService'

and the corresponding entry in applicationConfig.xml is :

```
<beans default-autowire="no" 
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="PopupAction" scope="prototype" class="com.common.actions.PopupAction" autowire="no">
        <constructor-arg type="com.common.services.abs.iIntermedService" ref="intermedService"/>
        <constructor-arg type="com.common.services.abs.iLocationService" ref="locationService"/>
        <constructor-arg type="com.common.services.abs.iUserService" ref="userService"/>
        <constructor-arg type="com.common.services.abs.iPhoneService" ref="phoneService"/>
    </bean>
```

why does spring trying to autowire this action as long as i defined the dependency by hand here and i defined `auto-wire="no"`?

Or this message tells me that the wiring was made by type via constructor(as i wanted) and "Autowiring by type" means that from the 4 params he matched intermedService with my variable intermed service by type (and not by order or something else)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Struts 2 Spring plugin sets autowiring to "name" by default. Currently I don't believe the plugin allows "none" as a value, but you could try using "auto"--I suspect this will not help, as it is still an autowiring bean factory.

This has been brought up before; I don't recall any real resolution. I've brought it up again to see if it can be addressed in the next release where we doing some significant cleanup.

*Edit* There's also the `struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire.alwaysRespect` constant which defaults to `false`; try setting it to `true`. I don't recall which sense of the boolean means which, or if it has the effect--looking in to it now.

Comment: Hi Dave, it seems that no matter what i do the auto wire is always on :). I`ll let this as it is for the moment. Maybe in the next versions of struts-spring plugin we will be able to disable this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

A way to get around it (until it gets fixed) is to just name your fields/constructor arguments and your beans differently, so that spring can't match them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe default-autowire="no" is enabled by default . i.e, if you don't specify default-autowire, it means default-autowire="no" . Try setting autowire-candidate="false" if you don't want this bean to be autowired http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html